# how control navigation bar and button in splash

Tags: android, navigationbar, splash-screen

## Android

Hello.

I want to adjust the size of devices resolution and splash image in the splash screen.
I did try to apply png file to 9patch.
But I made gap between device to navigation bar.

[image]

And I'd try, try, try, I have reached this point.

[image]

I don't know how control navigation bar and button.
Please please please, teach me how hide navigation bar in the splash screen or how change the color in navigation bar's buttons.

Kindly review and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have some code so we can suggest what could be improved.
But here is some suggestions from android developer documentation.

```
 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

read more here on how to hide navigation bar.
[Link](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation#java)

Comment: I saw this document. but it didn't apply to splash.